# SocketException error in custom networking(TCP) for Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, tcp, tcpclient

I'm having some trouble trying to run a server and client with in Unity. But I keep getting this error :
**"SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
"**

This error only happens when the Player.cs script is assigned to the player(since it is calling the `SendMovement` Method) 
then I get disconnected from the network, the error points out that it is coming from:

***ClientTCP.SendData (System.Byte[] data) (at Assets/Project/Networking/Scripts/ClientTCP.cs:109)***

***ClientTCP.SendMovement (Vector3 pos, Quaternion rot) (at Assets/Project/Networking/Scripts/ClientTCP.cs:124).***

So it's obviously something wrong with sending the data but I'm new to networking so I don't really know what I'm doing wrong :P
I'll put a link to the project files just to see if anyone can see what I am doing wrong.

project files : https://www.dropbox.com/s/484t7un2w4jj7a0/Networking.rar?dl=0

Comment: Put a break point on following line (line 109) by clicking on line and then press F9.  Then check cmd.exe window for messages :  myStream.Write(buffer.ToArray(), 0, buffer.ToArray().Length);  The connection is never opening or it is closing due to an error.

Comment: And how does that help me fix the error?

Comment: The error is occurring because the connection is closed which can happen for lots of reasons.  We first need to know the reason.

Comment: The reason from what I know is the SendMovement method, as soon as it gets called, you get disconnected from the server.

Comment: That is the clue.  I suspect the issue is with the zero packet length.   TCP has a keep-alive where packets are sent with zero length.  So you shouldn't close a connection just because you get a zero length packet.  You could also get a zero length message if there is an error in the server code that send a zero length packet.  Confirm by stepping through the code that the you are getting a zero length message.  Can't tell for sure.  You may want to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to help debug code and confirm that the server sent the zero length message.

Comment: Okay, so the SocketException occurs when the ConnectionID in the Player.cs is 0. Now we just need to figure out how to fix the packet problem, which might be something to not being able to Write something :P

Comment: As I said it could be the server sent a packet with zero bytes.  asyncBuffer never gets filled.  You ConnectCallback and OnReceiveData methods have issues.  See the msdn examples : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples

Comment: Thanks that example was helpful.